# Devexpress Popup menu with GridControl Popup menu

Tags: winforms, devexpress, popupmenu

Where I Right-Click on GridColumn To Popup the GridColumn Menu
It Pops up with the main Popup menu
[image]

Comment: any one can help

Comment: Show us the code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be caused by PopupMenu being called all over regardless of the location of the mouse.

Use event "PopupMenuShowing" to display the user menu in GridControl. You can implement this event to decide whether to display pop-ups based on the location of your mouse.

```
private void gridview1_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, PoupMenuShowingEventArgs e)
{
   // check in row and in cell
   if(!e.HitInfo.InRow && !e.HitInfo.InRowCell)
      return;

   // showing main(user) popup menu
   popupMenu1.ShowPopup(gridcontrol1.PointToScreen(new Point(e.Point.X, e.Point.Y)));
}
```